# Keeping a plot label from automatically resizing

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I have:

```
Clear[s, t]
s[t_] = 189 - 48 t - 11 t^2 + 2 t^3;
v[t_] = s'[t];
a[t_] = s''[t];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Arrowheads[{-0.02, 0.02}],
   Arrow[{{s[-6], 0}, {s[10], 0}}],
   Red, PointSize[Large],
   Point[{s[t], 0}]
   },
  PlotLabel -> 
   StringForm["Velocity = ``, Acceleration = ``", Round[v[t], .1], 
    Round[a[t], .1]]], {{t, -5}, -6, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I'd like to figure out the simplest way to keep the plot label from jumping around as the slider moves.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues:

1. The number of digits in "Velocity" and "Acceleration" change.
2. Even when the number of digits are equal you are not using a fixed width font so the space needed varies.

There are a few ways of addressing this. One method is to use `Grid` and `ItemSize` instead of `StringForm` to keep the space reserved for the numbers constant.

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{
   Arrowheads[{-0.02, 0.02}],
   Arrow[{{s[-6], 0}, {s[10], 0}}],
   Red, PointSize[Large],
   Point[{s[t], 0}]},
  PlotLabel ->
   Grid[{{"Velocity = ", Round[v[t], .1] , " Acceleration = ", Round[a[t], .1]}},
    ItemSize -> {{Automatic, {2 -> 4, 4 -> 4}}, Automatic}]
  ],
 {{t, -5}, -6, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Hope this helps.

---

`ItemSize` spec for OP's comment below.

In the **Details and Options** section for [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) have a read of the item *Settings for the options Alignment, Background, Frame, ItemSize, and ItemStyle can be given as follows to apply separately to different items* and *The $\text{spec}_{k}$ can have the following forms* directly underneath it.

The first specification is for the column widths and the second for the row heights.  It specifies `Automatic` widths for all columns except columns 2 and 4 as well as `Automatic` heights for all rows.

Comment: This does help, a very nice answer. However, I'm not understanding the ItemSize -> {{Automatic, {2 -> 4, 4 -> 4}}, Automatic}. I'm looking in the documentation and Automatic says "separately size items to fit within the total formatting width ." And I think 2->4 and 4->4 specifies the width for item 2 and 4 in the list to four character width, but I'm still not understanding. Would you mind adding a paragraph to your answer explaining this piece of the code? Thanks so much.

Comment: In the **Details and Options** section for [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) have a read of the item *Settings for the options Alignment, Background, Frame, ItemSize, and ItemStyle can be given as follows to apply separately to different items*.